# dhtmlx timeline skips weeks instead of skipping past the weekend to monday

Tags: javascript, html, scheduler, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

My `dhtmlx` timeline keeps skipping weeks instead of skipping the weekend to the Monday. I can't find out why it's doing this. I have added bits of code that should fix this but It doesn't!

## #

So far when I click to goto the next week, it will skip mulitple weeks at a time - Eg: It will go from the 6'th june up to the 18th of june! It keeps doing this throughout the program.

### Im trying to display the following date + time structure

Mon - Fri, 9 - 17:30

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        function init() {

            scheduler.locale.labels.timeline_tab = "Timeline";
            scheduler.locale.labels.section_custom="Section";
            scheduler.config.details_on_create=true;
            scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick=true;
            scheduler.config.xml_date="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";

            //===============
            //Configuration
            //===============
            var sections=[
                {key:1, label:"James Smith"},
                {key:2, label:"John Williams"},
                {key:3, label:"David Miller"},
                {key:4, label:"Linda Brown"}
            ];

            scheduler.createTimelineView({
                name:   "timeline",
                x_unit: "hour",
                x_date: "%H:%i",
                x_step: 0.5*2,
                x_size: 228/2,// 5 day
                y_unit: sections,
                y_property: "section_id",
                render:"bar",
                second_scale:{
                    x_unit: "day", // unit which should be used for second scale
                    x_date: "%F %d" // date format which should be used for second scale, "July 01"
                }
            });

            //Skip the weekend.
            scheduler.ignore_month = function(date){


            // 0 refers to Sunday, 6 - to Saturday
            // scheduler.ignore_timeline = function(date){
            //     if(date.getHours() < 9 || date.getHours() >= 18)
            //         return true;
            //     if (date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 0) //hides Saturdays and Sundays
            //         return true;
            // };

            scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeViewChange", function(old_mode,old_date,mode,date){
                if(old_date == undefined)
                    return true;
                else{
                    var new_date = old_date;
                 if(old_date < date)
                        new_date.setDate(old_date.getDate()-7);
                 else
                        new_date.setDate(old_date.getDate()+7);


                    updateView();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            function updateView(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    scheduler.updateView( new Date(2015,6,6) );
                }, 1000);
            }
                scheduler.attachEvent("onEventAdded", function(event_id,e){
                    var event = this.getEvent(event_id)
                    var day = event.start_date.getDay();
                    if(day==6 || day==0) this.deleteEvent(event_id)
                });
                // 0 refers to Sunday, 6 - to Saturday
scheduler.ignore_week = function(date){
    if (date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 0) //hides Saturdays and Sundays
        return true;

};
            //updateView();
//            setTimeout(function(){
//                scheduler.updateView( new Date(2015,6,6) );
//             }, 1000);


            //===============
            //Data loading
            //===============

            scheduler.config.lightbox.sections=[
                {name:"description", height:130, map_to:"text", type:"textarea" , focus:true},
                {name:"custom", height:23, type:"select", options:sections, map_to:"section_id" },
                {name:"time", height:72, type:"time", map_to:"auto"}
            ];
 if (date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 0) //hides Saturdays and Sundays
        return true;
};
            scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(2015,5,29),"timeline");
            scheduler.parse([
                { start_date: "2015-06-30 09:00", end_date: "2015-07-01 12:00", text:"Task A-12458", section_id:1},
                { start_date: "2015-06-30 10:00", end_date: "2015-06-30 21:00", text:"Task A-89411", section_id:1},
                { start_date: "2015-06-30 10:00", end_date: "2015-07-01 14:00", text:"Task A-64168", section_id:1},
                { start_date: "2015-06-30 16:00", end_date: "2015-07-02 17:00", text:"Task A-46598", section_id:1},

                { start_date: "2015-06-30 12:00", end_date: "2015-07-02 20:00", text:"Task B-48865", section_id:2},
                { start_date: "2015-06-30 14:00", end_date: "2015-06-30 18:00", text:"Task B-44864", section_id:2},
                { start_date: "2015-06-30 16:30", end_date: "2015-07-01 18:00", text:"Task B-46558", section_id:2},
                { start_date: "2015-06-30 18:30", end_date: "2015-07-01 00:00", text:"Task B-45564", section_id:2},

                { start_date: "2015-06-30 08:00", end_date: "2015-07-01 12:00", text:"Task C-32421", section_id:3},
                { start_date: "2015-07-01 14:30", end_date: "2015-07-02 16:45", text:"Task C-14244", section_id:3},

                { start_date: "2015-07-01 09:20", end_date: "2015-07-01 18:20", text:"Task D-52688", section_id:4},
                { start_date: "2015-06-30 11:40", end_date: "2015-06-30 21:30", text:"Task D-46588", section_id:4},
                { start_date: "2015-07-01 12:00", end_date: "2015-07-02 18:00", text:"Task D-12458", section_id:4}
            ],"json");
        }


    </script>
</head>
```

### Html

```
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
        <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
            <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="timeline_tab" style="right:280px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_header">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_data">
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the reply to your question here: http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=39524